# Dirichlet bayesian updating with unobserved

Tags: bayesian, dirichlet-distribution

Assume we have a weighted dice and we wish to estimate the probabilities after three people have rolled the dice. We assume a uniform prior for $\alpha=1$

Prior knowledge: $p \sim Dir(1,1,1,1,1,1) $

Alice rolled 100 times and obtained $\{4,2,36,0,11,47\}$

Updated knowledge: $p \sim Dir(5,3,37,1,12,48) $

Bob rolled 200 times and obtained $\{6, 3 , 88 , 1 ,24,78\}$

Updated knowledge: $p \sim Dir(11,  6 ,125 , 2 , 36 , 126) $

**Question:**
How would we update the probabilities if each person may have only partial knowledge? That is, if Bob could only see odds, for example.

Bob rolled 200 times, Charlie blocked Bob from seeing anything not odd, so Bob now obtained $\{6, - , 88 , - ,24 , -\}$

Likewise, Charlie could roll 150 times and Danielle blocked anything not 3 or 4, for example; seeing $\{-,-,63,5,-,-\}$

At first glance I thought of adding equal pseudo-counts to those not observed, that is Bob observed 118 out of 200, so add observed counts to each parameter but add 82/3 for the the three unobserved. Not sure if that is the optimal or correct procedure.

Comment: Bayesian resolution: Treat the unknowns as extra parameters and construct the corresponding posterior.